# Html и javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Используя языки программирования html и javascript нужно добавить функцию Color (), которая изменит цвет фона всех нечетных строк таблицы на оранжевый. Вызов функции следует подключить в кнопку типа „button“.
Proszę o dodanie funkcji pokoloruj  nieparzyste(), która zmieni kolor tła wszystkich
nieparzystych wierszy tabeli na pomarańczowy. Wywołanie funkcji należy podpiąć pod
przycisk typu „button“.

Comment: к чему подключать воздуху ?

Answer (score 0):

html - это не язык программирования. 
Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью псевдокласса css родительского элемента

```
table tr:nth-child(odd){
background: #D45800;
}
```